# С помощью selenium хочу получить количество подписок у пользователя в Instagram но каждый раз выдает разное число

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Цель получить все подписки пользователя в инстаграм но когда скролю подписки каждый раз разное количество.

```
fBody = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='isgrP']")
    scroll = 0
    while scroll < scroll_for:  # scroll 5 times
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', fBody)
        time.sleep(2)
        scroll += 1

    fList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']//li")
    print("fList len is {}".format(len(fList)))
```

Если подписок мало то он выдает точное число, если их много то число всегда разное с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Связано с тем, что этот код считает не количество подписок, а количество определенных элементов на странице. А когда подписок много, то они подгружаются по мере прокручивания страницы, а не все сразу, следовательно количество таких элементов на странице разное.

Comment: Я всегда гружу все элементы со страницы, то есть скрол идет всегда до конца